# Android no reproduce vídeo de m3u8

Tags: java, android, android-studio, stream

He estado teniendo un problema que no logro solucionar, y es que no he encontrado algún reproductor o librería para android o alguna forma de reproducir un formato m3u8, se que es un formato que almacena listas de reproducción de medios.
He intentado usar y probar varios reproductores que se supone que ayudan a trabajar este formato como lo es [exoPlayer derivacion](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/exoplayer), [exoMedia](https://github.com/brianwernick/ExoMedia), [exoPlayer completo](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer), [AdaptiveStreamingExoplayer](https://github.com/MayurSolanki/AdaptiveStreamingExoplayer), [FFmpegMediaPlayer](https://github.com/wseemann/FFmpegMediaPlayer), y muchos otros ejemplos mas, a lo mas que he llegado es a reproducir únicamente el audio, no logro reproducir el vídeo, no se a que se debe, pero no funciona, ahora para la reproducción de archivos mp4, mkv, y otros mas, si reproducen bien, audio y vídeo, pero eso no es lo que necesito, intente con este ejemplo [iptv.example](https://github.com/AlexanderSofronov/iptv.example), pero lo que necesita para que funcione, es otra aplicación que se debe descargar de la PlayStore, eso no es problema, el problema esta en que esa aplicación que se llama **IPTV CORE**, contiene adware [iptv.example](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ru.iptvremote.android.iptv.core), y no es de mi agrado estar mostrando adware a un usuario, cuando desea ver sus canales.

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```xml
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

   <application
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
```

**reproductor_activity.xml**

```xml
<VideoView
        android:id="@+id/videoViewXml"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

**ReproductorActivity.java**

```java
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_player);

        videoView = findViewById(R.id.videoViewXml);

        final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(PlayerActivity.this);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Please Wait");
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        progressDialog.show();

        MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);
        mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);
        videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);

        videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("http://xx.xxx.xx.xx:8000/live/xxxx/xxxx/99.m3u8"));
        videoView.start();

        videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
    }
```

De momento esto no funciona también.

Comment: Hola, te sugiero agregar el código de como lo tratas de reproducir, saludos.

Comment: ok, muchas gracias Jorge por la sugerencia

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He visto en internet varias respuestas, muchas sugieren usar una API u otro player, pero nativamente en realidad se puede reproducir el video .m3U8 sin problema, *el punto principal e importante es generar tu archivo .m3u8 con los codecs que son compatibles para el dispositivo.*

**[Android: Formatos soportados](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/media-formats)**

Actualmente es menos común encontrar dispositivos android que usen otro tipo de codecs, para .m3u8 usa:

- **AAC para Audio.**
- **H.263 o H.264 para Video.**

---

Este es un ejemplo usando un `VideoView`:

**How to play .M3U8 Streaming in Android**

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/myVideoView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

***Main.java***

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private String urlStream;
    private VideoView myVideoView;
    private URL url;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            myVideoView = (VideoView)this.findViewById(R.id.myVideoView);
            MediaController mc = new MediaController(this);
            myVideoView.setMediaController(mc);         
            urlStream = "http://jorgesys.net/i/irina_delivery@117489/master.m3u8";

            myVideoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(urlStream)); 

    }
}
```

No olvides agregar el permiso para acceso a internet:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

---

Actualización:

Si usas url no cifradas que solo usan http:// , agrega dentro de tu `AndroidManifest.xml` en el bloque `application` que permita este tipo de conexiones mediante `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` ejemplo:

```
<application
    ...
    ...
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```

Comment: muchas gracias @Jorgesys, pues de momento he probado muchas veces de esta manera pero el error que me devuelve siempre es: **/MediaPlayer: Couldn't open http://xx.xxx.xx.xx:8000/live/xxx/xxx/69.m3u8: java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider: http://xx.xxx.xx.xx:8000/live/xxx/xxx/69.m3u8**

Comment: @GrsnChml FileNotFoundException puede ser causado porque no tienes definido el permiso de internet o porque la url es incorrecta, revisa esto

Comment: gracias, pero si lo tengo agregado, lo acabo de modificar el la pregunta, pero si ya tenia permisos

Comment: Si estas usando sistema operativo 8 o posterior define  android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" para que permita la conexión o si puedes usa https:// @GrsnChml

Comment: ya lo tengo agregado al Manifest, pero aun no funciona

Comment: cuales son los codec usados para tu archivo m3u8 ?

Comment: el video se envia en mpg4, y mp3 el audio o acc

Comment: Logre encontrar la solucion, para los que lleguen a este lugar, la solucion estaba en el formato que me enviaba el servidor, los proveedores me estaban mintiendo del formato que me enviaban, ellos me decian que estaba en formato mp3 pero no era asi, hasta que logre que lo cambiaran y asi funciono, agradezco mucho tu respuesta

Comment: Excelente, un saludo @GrsnChml

Comment: Te agradezco bastante @Jorgesys

Answer (score 1):

Si tu error es FileNotFoundException, no creo que el problema sea de formato.

Asegurate de tener permisos de internet en tu manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Tambien cambiaria como estas haciendo el play:

```
videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("http://xx.xxx.xx.xx:8000/live/xxxx/xxxx/99.m3u8"));
videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener(){
   public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp){                  
      progressDialog.dismiss();     
      videoView.start();
   }
});
```

Comment: gracias por tu sugerencias, y si tengo permisos, pero aun asi no funciona